# Is pass by reference (a vector of pointers to object) faster than pass by value?

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have the following pass by reference:

`foo(std::vector<someClass *> const &bar)`

compares to pass by value

`foo(std::vector<someClass *> bar)`

I read that when it comes to primitive datatypes, using **pass by value** would be prefered whereas **pass by reference** for large data like class or struct. So what about *vector of pointers to objects*?

Comment: If you pass a vector of pointers by value, a copy of the vector of pointers will be made, in addition to a copy of the internal vector structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple about the amount of bytes that need to get copied.

When you pass an `int`, there is not much difference (if any) between its size and its pointer's size. Because the value is typically already in a register, it is slightly faster.

If you pass a larger structure or array, copying the content (for by-value) takes longer than copying its pointer (for by-ref).

*vector of pointers to objects* again could be many bytes, so reference is faster.